# How to use the countif function of excel in calculated column of list?

Tags: calculated-column

I have a calculated column in my list where I want to apply the countif function available in excel.

How can I do tht?

Please guide..

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no COUNTIF function in SharePoint.

Some alternative ways

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978057/can-i-create-a-countif-calculated-column-in-sharepoint

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931380/how-can-i-build-a-countif-function-in-sharepoint